# is there a way to prepend code through the command line of a compiler?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++, clang

suppose I have this:

```
int main() { return a; }
```

and I want to call the compiler and have it compile:

`g++ a.cpp --PREPEND-CODE-FLAG="int a = 5;"`

is there a way to do this?

Note that I know I can insert a preprocessor definition for `a` through the command line but I'm looking for a way to prepend real C++ code to the current translation unit.

currently I'm generating a separate header with that code and I'm including it with the `-I` flag for g++/clang

Comment: There is no "current translation unit" as you can pass multiple files to an invocation of compiler

Comment: What is the use case for this?

Comment: @Ben trust me - there is one. I'm trying to combat [this](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/V1_7_Primer.md#important-note-for-visual-c-users) issue for [my library](https://github.com/onqtam/doctest) through the build system (note that it is not only for visual studio - it affects all platforms and compilers).

I want an unintrusive way for force-linking every object file of a static library into the final dll/executable - and I want it coded in cmake.

Comment: in cmake, use the `configure_file` command...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've tagged this question with several tags pertaining to different C++ implementations, which suggests that you are looking for a cross-platform solution. None exists.

The standard does not specify how a translation unit is passed to the compiler; it never assumes that a translation unit is, for example, a single file. If you are using `g++` with a standard shell, you could, for example, compose a translation unit from the execution of several commands:

```
{
   echo 'int a = 5';
   echo '#line 1 a.cpp'
   cat a.cpp
} | g++ -Wall -x c++ -
```

That will work (with minor variations) with most C++ compilers available on a Unix platform, but is obviously not suitable for a Windows platform. Perhaps other things would be. But whatever solution you use will be individually crafted for the environment in which you are working.

Comment: I accept this because... as I suspected what I'm looking for doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ g++ -DPREPENDED_CODE="int a = 5;" nod.cpp
$ ./a.out
$ echo $?
5
$
```

where nod.cpp is:

```
PREPENDED_CODE

int main()
{
    return a;
}
```